# Questions about Installing Ubuntu on phones

Tags: discussion

There have been a lot of questions asked recently in the form of *How do I install Ubuntu on my $randomphone?* I'm not sure Ask Ubuntu is the right place for these questions.

While they fit the general concept of having a direct question, with a presumably direct enough answer, they also seem to be too specific. Every model of phone is different, and so there is no general answer that will work for all phones, like there is with installing Ubuntu on a PC. It requires someone with specific knowledge of the phone in question, to be able to provide a definite answer, and requires other users to have the exact same phone, for it to be generally useful to them.

Should these be closed as off topic, as they are better asked on another forum (such as XDA Developers)?

Comment: Yep - on-topic... and we already have a canonical Q&A we dupe to for these type of questions - http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-touch-support

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem with those questions. Questions about installing Ubuntu Desktop on a Vaio, HP, etc. laptops are fine. So why would phones be off topic?

I am not saying every single question should be accepted. Probably most of them should be flagged as duplicate to [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to xyz device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-xyz-device).

But I don't think they should be closed as off topic just because they are about a specific mobile device.